# Trying to print out contents of a DIV using positioning placement while keeping the CSS Values?

Tags: php, css, html, printing

I have anew project to where I need to display a certificate on the screen and also have the ability to print it out on a hard copy printer.  I am needing to display 4 fields that are based on the users grade class or course taken.  My issue is I am using CSS to display the image of the certificate as a background image within a DIV, as far as the other 4 variable fields I am using relative positioning with TOP and LEFT for placement on the screen.  As far as the Screen goes, it looks great but when I print it out to a PDF or a hard copy I lose the positioning of the fields.  They are below the image on the paper and don't retain their CSS values either ... Not sure what the best way to program something like this?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  I have scoured the web with many articles, tried various solutions to no avail.  Can you use CSS for placement when printing out contents within a DIV? Is this something that's easily done in Javascript as a client rather than using PHP along with CSS, HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for print can be tough, in part because testing it involves getting to a print preview state again and again, on different browsers. And different browsers can interpret printed CSS with dramatic differences.

If you are printing something that you know will be taking up less than one page, I'd recommend you use absolute positioning for just about everything. Instead of pixels or ems, use inches (or percentages) as your unit of measure. Don't forget you can also just set your `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` of an absolute element, rather than specifying a width or height.

@Protonfish is right about using a print-only stylesheet. You can also address a specific set of rules within your regular stylesheet using `@media print { rules here }`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS placement should work fine for print, except when it doesn't. I can't be certain what is causing your specific issues, but I can suggest a way that I would try to fix it.

In your HTML, create a separate style block like so:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
/* Put print-specific styles here */
</style>
```

You can throw whatever CSS you want in there and it will only affect the printed appearance - you won't mess up the screen layout at all. See if you can fix it this way. Good luck.